# Why doesn't Evolution send outgoing emails?

Tags: 10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evolution does not send mail from Yahoo or Hotmail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25260/evolution-does-not-send-mail-from-yahoo-or-hotmail)

I have recently installed Ubuntu 10.10 but have had a problem with the Evolution E-Mail system which accepts incoming E-Mails perfectly but will not sent any outgoing E-Mails.

When I attempt to send an E-Mail message this just moves to the outbox and stays there.

What could I have done wrong when setting up Evolution to have caused this?

Comment: You seem to have already asked this question?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your outgoing email settings!